# Don't let UILabel overlap another label in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a titleLabel on the left, and a detail label on the right, similar to the `Right Detail` cell type.

[image]

Current neither `UILabel` has a set width, which is what I want. However the `titleLabel` sometimes is very long and overlaps the detail label on the right.

**How can I give a margin between the two labels, ONLY if the `titleLabel` is too long and will overlap?**

Comment: Create a `>=` constraint from the trailing edge of the first label to the leading edge of the second label.

Comment: @dan After I posted this I realized this is what I should be doing. Now I feel dumb. :) Can you post an answer?

Comment: @dan, how do I add a `>=` using Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing what you can do, is set minimum space between them by putting relation `GraterThenOrEqual` for example at 10 pixels.
Or there is a dodgy way to it by playing with priority with constraints. You may set priority of constraint between as 750.

In the interface builder you have to set space between the labels, and then select manually this constraint, then you will see the menu[image]

called Relation, just choose there `GraterOrEqual`

Comment: How do I add a `>=` in my storyboard? Control-dragging between the two doesn't give me that option.

Comment: Doing that actually pushes the `detailLabel` off the screen and I can no longer see it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa460mra9uiv4ey/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-07%20at%2010.38.52%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: @NicHubbard so set the compression resistance priority for detailLabel more than for first one. By doing that your first label will be squashed instead of detail. Is that what you want?

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. Never really had to do this before in autolayout, so wasn't used to it.

Comment: @NicHubbard so, read more about Compression Resistance and Hugging Priority and intrinsic content size to understand fully how iOS manage views with autolayout.